# Go substring operation, no index out of range?

Tags: go

I would like know why "s[1:]" in the 2nd fmt.Println isn't throwing an index out of range error? Index 1 is clearly out of range

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

   s := "J"

   //fmt.Println(s[1]) // This results in a runtime error: index out of range

   fmt.Println(s[1:]) // Why does this work? Index value 1 is clearly out of range, but the statement prints an empty string

}
```

Answer (score 12):

As the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) states, given a slice expression

```
a[low : high]
```

> For arrays or strings, **the indices are in range if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range.** [...] If the indices are out of range at run time, a run-time panic occurs.

In your example

```
s[1:]
```

the `low` is `1`, `high` is `len(s)` and `len(s)` is `1`. Since `low <= len(s)`, there's no panic.

Answer (score 2):

It is, [by definition](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions), not out of range: any position from 0 to `len(s)` can be the beginning or the end of a range on `s`. The way that slice endpoints work is designed so that you can write correct code without a lot of extra checks or arithmetic. In particular,

```
first  = s[:x]
second = s[x:]
```

will split `s` into two parts, with `first` having `x` bytes and `second` having the remainder of the string, for *any* value of `x` between 0 and `len(s)`. `first` will be an empty string if `x == 0`, and `second` will be an empty string if `x == len(s)`. This can only be true if the full range of values from 0 to `len(s)` is allowed, otherwise at least one of the possible split positions wouldn't be expressible.